# Zsh function: forward completion to subfunction

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, bash-completion, zsh-completion

Many times I end up writting wrapper function around existing ones, for instance:

```
function gl {
    some_computed_stuff=...
    git --no-pager log --reverse $some_computed_stuff "$@"
}
function m {
    make "$@" && notify-send success || notify-send failed
}
```

I know that aliases keep autocompletion but sometimes functions are required and in that case autocompletion is lost. 
For instance here I would like to keep `git log` completion for my function `gl` or `make` completion for `m`.

I tried to add `compctl -K _git gl` but no suggestions are made. It won't work anyway since I must somehow find how to provide `log` argument to `_git` autocompletion script as well, so my question is:

Is there a way to make ZSH (but also bash) understand that typing `gl` is the exact equivalent of `git log`? Something like (for ZSH only):

```
compctl 'git log' gl
compctl 'make' m
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For zsh, you can create a new completion with [compdef](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Functions-2) function.

In its basic form it associates a completion function with a word. Provided that zsh comes with lots of completions already built-in, one can just reuse those. For example, for `m` function from the question:

```
$ compdef _make m
```

As per documentation, you can also define a completion for a specific service, if the one is defined in the completion function. Again, as zsh comes with `_git` completion and it already defines `git-log` service, a `gl` function from the question may be autocompleted with:

```
$ compdef _git gl=git-log
```

On Linux, you can see existing completion implementations in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/`. You can read the completion implementations to see what services they define.